# WPF bind DataGrid column ComboBox from database table using id

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, datacontext

I have classes

```
[Table(Name = "Categories")]
class Category
{
    [Column(Name = "CategoryID", IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
    private int CategoryID { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[Table(Name = "Products")]
class Product
{
    [Column(Name = "ProductID", IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "CategoryID")]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "Price")]
    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

and i need to create DataGrid column as ComboBox using CategoryID from Products and put all categories in ComboBox from Categories for editing, how can i make it with using DataContext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I have created `ObservableCollection` of  Product and Category with name `ProductSet` & `ListOfCategory` in the Window level.

```
public ObservableCollection<Category> ListOfCategory { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<Product> ProductSet  { get; set; }
```

I have created both the `ObservableCollection` in the Code behind of the Window, You can create this in view model which is better approach.

I have named the Window as "Window1"  x:Name="Window1"

As you need to bind the data context, did the `elementBinding` with Window1 and also set the `ItemsSource="{Binding ProductSet}"`. So what happens here is the `ProuctSet` is searched for `DataContext`, which is in turn searched inside `Window1` Class.

For `DataGridComboBoxColumn`, set the `ItemsSource` using the Style and search for the `Datagrid` `DataContext` which has `ListOfCategory` using Relative Source.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:Name="DataGrid1"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="135" Margin="21,288,0,0"
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="729"
    DataContext="{Binding ElementName=Window1}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding ProductSet}" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ProductID" Width="175"
            Binding="{Binding ProductID}"/>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Category"
            DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="CategoryID"
            SelectedItemBinding="{Binding ListOfCategory}">
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource"
                    Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.ListOfCategory,
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                    AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding
                    Path=DataContext.ListOfCategory,RelativeSource=
                    {RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                    AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="175" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Price " Width="175"
            Binding="{Binding Price }"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

If you going to bind using View model, then provide the Class Name of the `Viewmodel` instead of Element Binding.